# How to select columns according to values in a column?

Tags: r

I'd like to acquire the values from certain columns. The columns are different for each row and depend on the values from another column. The example below should speak for itself.

Here's what I have:

```
id   year   data.2014   data.2015
1    2014   21          22
2    2015   23          24
```

Here's what I'd like to have:

```
id   year   data.2014   data.2015   data
1    2014   21          22          21
2    2015   23          24          24
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could vectorize this by just adding `data.` to `df$year` and matching it in the column names

```
indx <- match(paste0("data.", df$year), names(df))
df$data <- df[cbind(1:nrow(df), indx)]
df
#   id year data.2014 data.2015 data
# 1  1 2014        21        22   21
# 2  2 2015        23        24   24
```

Another option is to work on a long format data and then join back to the original data by `id`

```
library(data.table)
indx <- melt(setDT(df), id = 1:2)[variable == paste0("data.", year), .(id, value)]
df[indx, data := i.value, on = "id"]
df
#    id year data.2014 data.2015 data
# 1:  1 2014        21        22   21
# 2:  2 2015        23        24   24
```

Answer (score 1):

If your years columns are sorted this way, you can do something like:

```
data <-  data.frame(id=1:2, year=2014:2015, data.2014=c(21,23), data.2015=c(22,24))

tmp <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
  tmp <- c(tmp, data[i, 3+data$year[i]-2014])
}
data$test <- tmp
data
```